# Producing all groups of fixed-length combinations

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm and/or Python code to generate all possible ways of partitioning a set of `n` elements into zero or more groups of `r` elements and a remainder. For example, given a set:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

with `n = 5` and `r = 2`, I would like to get

```
((1,2,3,4,5),)
((1,2),(3,4,5))
((1,3),(2,4,5))
...
((1,2),(3,4),(5,))
((1,2),(3,5),(4,))
...
```

In other words, the result of extracting 0 groups of two items from the set, plus the results of extracting 1 group of two items from the set, plus the results of extracting 2 groups of two from the set,... if `n` were larger, this would continue.

The order in which these results are generated is not important, and neither is the order of elements within each individual group, nor the order of the groups within a result. (e.g. `((1,3),(2,4,5))` is equivalent to `((3,1),(4,5,2))` and to `((2,5,4),(1,3))` and so on.) What I'm looking for is that every distinct result is produced at least once, and preferably exactly once, in as efficient a manner as possible.

---

The brute force method is to generate all possible combinations of `r` out of the `n` elements, then create all possible groups of any number of those combinations (the [powerset](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes)), iterate over them and only process the ones where the combinations in the group have no elements in common. That takes *far* too long for even a small number of elements (it requires iterating over 2^(n!/r!(n-r)!) groups, so the complexity is double-exponential).

Based on the code given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886476/enumeration-of-all-possible-two-member-group-constellations), which is essentially the special case for `r = 2` and `n` even, I've come up with the following:

```
def distinct_combination_groups(iterable, r):
    tpl = tuple(iterable)
    yield (tpl,)
    if len(tpl) > r:
        for c in combinations(tpl, r):
            for g in distinct_combination_groups(set(tpl) - set(c), r):
                yield ((c,) + g)
```

which does seem to generate all possible results, but it includes some duplicates, a nontrivial number of them when `n` is fairly large. So I'm hoping for an algorithm that will avoid the duplicates.

Comment: here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222780/enumeration-of-partitions, in the answer, you can find a link to the fascicle 3b of the 4th volume of Knuth's "The art of computer programming"

Comment: @Teudimundo: your link is about the problem of finding the partitions of *n* elements into exactly *k* sets, of any size. But the OP here wants partitions of *n* elements into any number of sets of size exactly *r* (plus possibly some remainder).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this?

```py
from itertools import combinations

def partitions(s, r):
    """
    Generate partitions of the iterable `s` into subsets of size `r`.

    >>> list(partitions(set(range(4)), 2))
    [((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 2), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 2))]
    """
    s = set(s)
    assert(len(s) % r == 0)
    if len(s) == 0:
        yield ()
        return
    first = next(iter(s))
    rest = s.difference((first,))
    for c in combinations(rest, r - 1):
        first_subset = (first,) + c
        for p in partitions(rest.difference(c), r):
            yield (first_subset,) + p

def partitions_with_remainder(s, r):
    """
    Generate partitions of the iterable `s` into subsets of size
    `r` plus a remainder.

    >>> list(partitions_with_remainder(range(4), 2))
    [((0, 1, 2, 3),), ((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 2), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 2))]
    >>> list(partitions_with_remainder(range(3), 2))
    [((0, 1, 2),), ((1, 2), (0,)), ((0, 2), (1,)), ((0, 1), (2,))]
    """
    s = set(s)
    for n in xrange(len(s), -1, -r): # n is size of remainder.
        if n == 0:
            for p in partitions(s, r):
                yield p
        elif n != r:
            for remainder in combinations(s, n):
                for p in partitions(s.difference(remainder), r):
                    yield p + (remainder,)
```

The example from the OP:

```
>>> pprint(list(partitions_with_remainder(range(1, 6), 2)))
[((1, 2, 3, 4, 5),),
 ((4, 5), (1, 2, 3)),
 ((3, 5), (1, 2, 4)),
 ((3, 4), (1, 2, 5)),
 ((2, 5), (1, 3, 4)),
 ((2, 4), (1, 3, 5)),
 ((2, 3), (1, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 5), (2, 3, 4)),
 ((1, 4), (2, 3, 5)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 4, 5)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4, 5)),
 ((2, 3), (4, 5), (1,)),
 ((2, 4), (3, 5), (1,)),
 ((2, 5), (3, 4), (1,)),
 ((1, 3), (4, 5), (2,)),
 ((1, 4), (3, 5), (2,)),
 ((1, 5), (3, 4), (2,)),
 ((1, 2), (4, 5), (3,)),
 ((1, 4), (2, 5), (3,)),
 ((1, 5), (2, 4), (3,)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 5), (4,)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 5), (4,)),
 ((1, 5), (2, 3), (4,)),
 ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5,)),
 ((1, 3), (2, 4), (5,)),
 ((1, 4), (2, 3), (5,))]
```

Comment: That works :-) Ideally I would have liked an explanation of the algorithm too, but it was easy enough to figure out from the code.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: I thought it would be more fun to let you reverse-engineer it!

Comment: Both [more_itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/) and [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_partitions) contain many partitioning functions, but I couldn't find one that allows to specify the size of the subsets like this. I suspect if you were to propose `partitions` and `partitions_with_remainder` in a pull request to more_itertools, they would accept it.

Comment: @Stef You know, I would not have thought that this algorithm is generally useful enough to be worth including in more_itertools, but it's probably a good idea to propose it, at least! (I would of course leave that up to Gareth as it's not my code to share)

Comment: I can believe there might be a use case for `partitions` (under a better name), but not for `partitions_with_remainder`. But in either case you are welcome to take my code and make a pull request, as I agreed to license it under CC-BY-SA when I posted it here. (You'd want to modernize the code first, of course—`range` instead of `xrange` and so on.)

Comment: (sorry I just saw this) I don't think that's legally valid; CC-BY-SA requires that any derivative works also be shared under the same license, but I can't contribute the code to more-itertools unless I'm allowed to distribute it under the MIT license (or, technically, grant someone else permission to distribute it under MIT). Not that I'm really worried about you suing or anything ;-) but I do think it'd be best coming from you; or at least I'd want to have an MIT license release in some less ephemeral form than a comment.

Comment: Send me an e-mail (gdr@garethrees.org) and I'll reissue you the code under an MIT license.