# Find all ways of partitioning two sets into n bins of size m, where all items in the first set (but not the second) must be included

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

The particular instance of this problem I have - finding all of the combinations of players of length *s* that can fit onto *n* courts (which contain *m* players each).

However, there's an additional constraint: some players *must* be included on at least one court. Let's have them be "Set_A". The remaining places available on the courts are filled from players in "Set_B".

A toy example with the desired output:

```
Set_A = {0, 1, 2}
Set_B = {3, 4}

def func(set_a, set_b, courts, court_size):
  #insert code here
  return answer

>>>func(Set_A, Set_B, 2, 2)
(((0,1),(2,3)),((0,1),(2,4)),((0,2),(1,3)),((0,2),(1,4)),((0,3),(1,2)),((0,4),(1,2)))
```

In a real example, there may be 3 courts which fit 4 players each. There are 10 players in "Set_A", and 12 players in "Set_B". I want to find all combinations that include all 10 players from "Set_A" and exactly 2 from "Set_B".

The following code (that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559946/producing-all-groups-of-fixed-length-combinations)) is sufficient for finding all combinations when the spaces on court are equal to number of the players in "Set_A", e.g. by calling `list(partitions(range(12), 4))`:

```
def partitions(s, r):
"""
Generate partitions of the iterable `s` into subsets of size `r`.

>>> list(partitions(set(range(4)), 2))
[((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 2), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 2))]
"""
s = set(s)
assert(len(s) % r == 0)
if len(s) == 0:
    yield ()
    return
first = next(iter(s))
rest = s.difference((first,))
for c in combinations(rest, r - 1):
    first_subset = (first,) + c
    for p in partitions(rest.difference(c), r):
        yield (first_subset,) + p
```

However, it's not sufficient for my purposes.

Another issue is speed and memory. 'partitions(16,4)' takes ~14 seconds each run, and 'partitions(20,4)' returns a MemoryError. It may well be that combinatorial explosion means it's simply intractable for some values I want to work with. (However, I think most of the time it'll be plausible, especially if these computations are cached for later look-up).

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.  I'd guess your MemoryError suggests you don't have enough RAM to just throw at the NP growth of your algorithm.  You may want to focus on how you could reduce your problem before getting the cache involved.

Comment: @Ed Grimm Actually, it's for a badminton match-making program I've written. I can sort 12 players into three courts (or 16 into four), but if there are (e.g.) 20 players available to go onto three courts, I'd like to be able to evaluate every combination of those (if computable in a reasonable amount of time).

Comment: If I'm reading the code reported in the documentation for itertools.combinations correctly, while it should be only making the case for your code about 23 times harder, I don't think it's reducing the work for itself - rather than avoiding the repeat cases, it's just filtering through them.  Which could mean it's doing roughly 116,280 times the effort.  I wouldn't be surprised at all if the Python team's solution to the lousy performance of the naive (n!)/(r!(n-r)!) algorithm was to just write it in C and hope -O2 could work it out.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at your problem wrong, and trying premature optimization to boot.

You're not trying to see all the combinations of 20 players in 12 slots.  Combinations doesn't care about order, so you have two sets.  Set_A just occupies slots, so you really just want to see the combinations of the 12 set B players in the remaining 2 slots.

If you want to see all the different ways those players could be filling the three courts, do that after you've figured out who might be playing.  It's still not combinations, because combinations doesn't do order.  I'm not sure permutations is applicable, either, because of the complexity of the two sets.

Figure out what detail level within each court you care about - if it's just which four players are in each court, then the 20 players on three courts case gives you 45 combinations of (set_A + the sets of 2 from set_B) to put into the first court, then the 22,275 sets of players that didn't get into the first court to see who goes in the second court, and who goes in the third court.  That basically gives you 1.5 million different possibilities of who is in each court.  But if you care who is going up against who, or who is in each space on the court, then... all I can do is wish you good luck and good night.

Comment: What I've done: call a cost function (where the min cost = "best" game) on every combo of selecting 4 players (a "court") from the players to be selected. For each court, there are three relevant combos (AB vs CD, AC vs BD and AD vs BC). The min of these three costs is saved to a dictionary with a tuple of the corresponding players (actually integers representing indices) as the key. Then for every court combo, calculate its cost by adding together the costs retrieved from dict calls. Return the combo with the min cost. For 12 players/3 courts, this takes ~0.1 secs, for 16/4, ~4 secs.